# Using go's sqlx to insert record in postgres table with automatic ID generation

Tags: postgresql, go, sqlx

I am using [`sqlx`](https://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/) to create a `go` api.

I want to insert a record in a table named `day`.

The corresponding `go` struct is the following

```golang
type Day struct {
    ID      string         `db:"id" json:"id"`
    Dateday string         `db:"dateday" json:"dateday"`
    Nameday string         `db:"nameday" json:"nameday"`
    Holyday bool           `db:"holyday" json:"holyday"`
}
```

In an endpoint for Day creation, will be receiving all fields but the `ID` via a post request

What method should I use to interact with my db so as to:

a) create the record

b) not need to pass the `ID` myself and instruct `postgres` to auto-generate the field.

The table creation statement is the following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "day" (
  "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  "dateday" date NOT NULL,
  "nameday" varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  "holyday" boolean NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to override the `MarshalJSON` method as mentioned below:

```
func (r Day) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    root := make(map[string]interface{})

    root["dateday"] = r.Dateday
    root["nameday"] = r.Nameday
    root["holyday"] = r.Holyday
    return json.Marshal(root)
}
```

Ref: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#example__customMarshalJSON